# Post and Portfolio Slug

Tags: php

I'm having this issue with using slug on portfolio page for a website being developed. Let me explain. I have a blog post that display the url as slug using htaccess. This is working. But now trying to use same for portfolio page coming from the database and it gives me no page found.

Below is the htaccess file

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ single.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portfolio-single.php?page=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php
```

And below is the portfolio-single.php page code

```php
if(empty($_GET['page'])) {
    Url::Redirect("/");
} else {
   if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
       $portfolio = Post::getPostById($conn, $_GET['page']);
   }
}
```

Please I need help in resolving this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: `^(.*)$` is a "catch-all" rule that will match everything, so it doesn't make sense to have two of them. It will always just use the first it finds (single.php). The rewrite module won't know which URL should go to which php file. You need to have some prefix to differentiate between them.

Comment: Thank you. Please, so how do I specifically target single.php and portfolio-single.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want different requests to be rewritten to different files, you need to tell the rewrite modules what requests should go where. This can be done by just adding a prefix to one of them.

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l [NC]

// Start with the portfolio
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ portfolio-single.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

// And have the "catch all" last (so it only catches requests that doesn't match 
// any of the more specific rules.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ single.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php
```

The above will now make all requests that starts with `/portfolio` to be rewritten to the portfolio page while all the other requests will be handled by the single page.

This however means that you need to make sure all URL's to the portfolio starts with `/portfolio` (or what ever slug you want to use).

Comment: Thank you Magnus Eriksson. Still didn't work. Maybe I'm not understanding the /portfolio.